# How does tensorflows's session.run's fetch argument can be output from another function without declaring it as a placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following simplified code below:

```
class someClass():
 def __init__(self):
   self.u_pred, self.v_pred = self.fnc(self.x_tf, self.y_tf)
   self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                                     log_device_placement=True))
   def predict(self, x, y):
    
     tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x, self.y_tf: y}
    
     u = self.sess.run(self.u_pred, tf_dict)
     v = self.sess.run(self.v_pred, tf_dict)
     return u, v
```

Here how does sess.run able to fetch `self.u_pred` and `self.v_pred` when they are not even part of the graph as they havent been declared using `tf.placeholder`?
After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126143/example-or-explanation-for-tensorflows-session-run-feed-dict-method-what-does) question, my understanding is that session calls the `tf.placeholder` and fetches the first argument passed and evaluates with the dictionary provided.

So in this case does `self.sess.run(self.u_pred, tf_dict)` able to automatically find `self.fnc()` and plugs in `tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x, self.y_tf: y}` to auto-evaluate the function?